# Raspberry Pi Drum Module

Tags: audio, analog-to-digital

I have an old electric drum set with a broken sound module (the brain that you plug each jack into). As a fun DIY project I'd like to resurrect this drum kit by replacing the sound module with the Raspberry Pi and playing audio samples for each drum pad that is hit. I'm new to electronics though, so I'd like your help getting started. What's the best way to go about this? I was thinking of using the GPIO and an ADC, but since I'm new to all this, I wanted to check in and see if this is the best route for 8 input jacks. If there's a USB solution then I'm sure that'd be easier, but I'd like to understand what that's all about too.

UPDATE: The sound module may also include a MIDI interface, so any help in that direction would be helpful as well. Here are the specs:

- The sound module is a Roland Percussion Sound Module TD-3 (serial #: EV28422)
- [Pic #1 of inside the module](http://bit.ly/13wkIgQ)
- [Pic #2 of inside the module](http://bit.ly/1CpnSlm)

Comment: Is the drum module a midi controller? or simply converting an analog signal to digital?

Comment: @SteveRobillard - Is there a way to tell? The drum pads each have a large audio jack that used to (when it worked) plug into the drum module and I could pick different drum sounds from the screen. It also could distinguish how hard you hit the pad, if that helps. I just assumed that it converted an analog  signal to digital and played certain sound files, but I'm not sure. If you know how to tell, I can check tonight.

Comment: A couple of pics of the whole system and the connectors would help, also any labels and a specific manufacturer and part  number would help.

Comment: @SteveRobillard - The sound module I'm trying to replace is a Roland Percussion Sound Module TD-3. The serial number is EV28422. Since it no longer works I dissected it and here are the innards if that helps: http://bit.ly/13wkIgQ and http://bit.ly/1CpnSlm . Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I can't say for sure but this is definitely more than a simple ADC. It looks like it includes a midi interface and is more of a drum pad controlled synth. So that others may be able to help you more than I can, you should add the additional information to the question so others don't need to read through all the comments to get the pertinent information. You may also want to check on one of the drummer sites, they may be able to help more with info about the board.